# Unable to install PyTorch despite having a valid Python version?

Tags: python, installation, pip, pytorch

I downgraded my python version to 3.10.2 ( It used to be 3.11.6) but I still get the error:

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch**

when I run:

pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio or pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu

I have an AMD Chip and no external GPU. The installed Python Version is also 64 bit

I downgraded as well and ran the commands given by the pytorch website. What could be the issue?

Comment: you need to `pip install torch` on whichever version you are using...

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a network issue since the found version displayed is None, you can try to install torch with the torch repo specified, like this example:

```
pipenv install --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/ "torch==1.10.1+cu113"
```

refer from https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4961